# Installing angularjs 1.3 beta bower package automatically installs older angular package

Tags: angularjs, bower

When I do in my terminal:

bower install angular#1.3.0-beta.18 --save

It does not only install the bower package 1.3.0-beta.18
but it also installs the bower package 1.2.16

WHY do I have now 2 packages?

That is what happened in my terminal:

```
C:\ipml>bower install angularjs#1.3.0-beta.18 --save
bower angular#>= 1.0.8          cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.22
bower angular#>= 1.0.8        validate 1.2.22 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>= 1.0.8
bower angular#1.2.16            cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.16
bower angular#1.2.16          validate 1.2.16 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.16
bower angular#>=1               cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.22
bower angular#>=1             validate 1.2.22 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>=1
bower angularjs#1.3.0-beta.18   cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.0-beta.18
bower angularjs#1.3.0-beta.18 validate 1.3.0-beta.18 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.0-beta.18
bower angular#1.2.16           install angular#1.2.16
bower angularjs#1.3.0-beta.18  install angularjs#1.3.0-beta.18

angular#1.2.16 bower_components\angular

angularjs#1.3.0-beta.18 bower_components\angularjs
```

Comment: What version of bower do you have? Is there a bower.json in the directory you run that command?

Comment: Running your command in an empty directory installs only 1.3-beta.18 I am using bower 1.3.9 on OSX

Comment: This is so stupid, why does bower give the same package two names and they somehow resolve as separate packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already angular 1.2.6 into your bower.json file and it's because you wrote :

> bower install angularjs#1.3.0-beta.18 --save

instead of

> bower install angular#1.3.0-beta.18 --save

So it added angularjs package and not updated angular package, you can look into your bower.json file and see both dependencies "angular" & "angularjs", remove the version you don't want.

It's the same package anyway, you can use :

> bower info package

To display from which source they are coming.

Also look into your bower_components folder, both package got a file named .bower.json with all the information about the version.

You can also delete all bower package that are not referenced into bower.json by running

> bower prune